# Side by side chart with Chart js but responsive not working on different page

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I have two charts aligned side my side and responsive but when i use the same chart in different screen(html page) the responsive doesn't work at all.

I have the same chart same CSS style.

Screen one where the chart is responsive:
[image: Screen one where the chart is responsive]

Screen two where the chart isn't working:
[image: Screen two where the chart isn't working]

**Line chart js code**

```
let draw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;

Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function () {
    draw.apply(this, arguments);
    let ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
    let _stroke = ctx.stroke;
    ctx.stroke = function () {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowColor = "#2b3840";
      ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 3;
      _stroke.apply(this, arguments);
      ctx.restore();
    };
  },
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
var labels = [
  "01 Jul",
  "02 Jul",
  "03 Jul",
  "04 Jul",
  "05 Jul",
  "06 Jul",
  "07 Jul",
];

Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.usePointStyle = true;

var data = {
  fill: false,
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      fill: false,
      label: "Negative",
      data: [25, 50, 20, 90, 80, 75, 99, 59, 40],
      borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
      borderWidth: 5,
      pointRadius: 0,
    },
    {
      fill: false,
      label: "Positive",
      data: [20, 30, 50, 15, 70, 34, 39, 32, 40],
      borderColor: ["rgba(80, 204, 168, 1)"],
      borderWidth: 5,
      pointRadius: 0,
    },
  ],
};
var options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 50,
      right: 50,
      top: 50,
      bottom: 50,
    },
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Rezultatet sipas pikëve",
    fontFamily: "Raleway",
    fontColor: "#434a52",
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          // Remove vertical lines
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  backgroundColor: "white",

  data: data,
  options: options,
});
```

**Pie chart js code**

```
Pie Chart js code 
var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");

var config = {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [10, 38, 30, 48],
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgb(246,69,115)",
          "rgb(255,152,1)",
          "rgb(0,162,255)",
          "rgb(124,179,26)",
        ],
        label: "Nota",
      },
    ],
    labels: ["Nota 5", "Nota 6-7", "Nota 8-9", "Nota 10"],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
    },
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 50,
        right: 50,
        top: 50,
        bottom: 50,
      },
    },
  },
};

var myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

**Screen one html code**

```
<div class="chart_line_div">
              <div class="line_chart"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class=""></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class=""></div></div></div>
                <canvas id="lineChart" height="407" style="display: block; height: 407px; width: 1067px;" width="1067" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
              </div>
              <div class="pie_chart">
                <canvas id="pieChart" height="800" width="600" style="display: block; height: 400px; width: 300px;"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Screen two html code**

```
 <div class="chart_line_div">
              <div class="line_chart">
                <canvas id="lineChart" height="400"></canvas>
              </div>
              <div class="pie_chart">
                <canvas id="pieChart" height="400"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.chart_line_div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px 0 rgba(202, 202, 217, 0.57);
    
}

.line_chart {
    width: 70%;
    border-right: 1.5px solid #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.pie_chart {
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in a simple blank page. I made simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7e01atvu/  It should be about the second page's parent element. can you show full html?